# Push classes form Eclipse to GitHub repository

Tags: java, github

I am working on a school project with my teammates and we are all new to GitHub. I have successfully pushed my project to our repository through Eclipse but I am unsure how to push new classes that my teammates or I have created to the existing project. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why would the process of doing a second push be different than the first one?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `git add .` to add all changed files and new files or `git add
   <filename>` for a specific file
2. `git commit -m "Add commit message here"`
3. `git push` to push it to the remote github repo

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using windows open the git bash client from the programs or open the terminal and go to the current git directory if your using Mac or Linux
2. Make sure you are in the root folder of your project...
3. Using “git status” you would see the list of the changes that you have done locally...
4. Make sure all the files are in the list...
5. Using “git add -A” add all the files
6. Then using “git commit -a” commit the files and insert message.
7. Then using “git push” you can push your files to the repository...

Answer (score 0):

In the eclipse there is plugin for git and then you can right click on the file and git add and commit to your repository...